# Ffmpeg encoding too slow

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, encoding

I'm using a Python script to encode mp4 videos in various qualities, in my case 360 +720 +1080.
Ffmpeg encoding videos very slow, 1 video taking 2 hours or more, I'm using good dedicated server from hetzner (ryzen 5 3600 + 64gm ram), any suggestion to improve speed will be really appreciated

```
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
from rich import print
import time
import sys
import pymysql as sql
import move

MYSQL_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
MYSQL_USER = ""
MYSQL_PASSWORD = ""
MYSQL_DB = ""

BASE_PATH = ''
UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'upload')
UPLOAD_PATH2 = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'upload2')
VIDEO_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'video')
LOGO_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'logo.png')
ERROR_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'error')
RCLONE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'rclone')
WAIT = 60
VIDEO_LENGTH = 10
MOVE_CMD = "screen -dmS move python3 move.py --folder {}"

global current_video_id

db = sql.connect(
        host=MYSQL_HOST,
        user=MYSQL_USER,
        password=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=MYSQL_DB
    )

def executedb(query):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    db.commit()

def time_now():
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return now

def write_log(msg):
    log_msg = f"{time_now()}: {msg}"
    with open('log.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(log_msg)
        f.write('\n')

def change_extension(files):
    for file in files:
        os.rename(file, file.split('.')[0] + '.mkv')

def change_all_videos_extension():
    # changing all the vidoe's extension to mkv format
    MKV_files = glob.glob('*.MKV')
    AVI_files = glob.glob('*.AVI')
    avi_files = glob.glob('*.avi')
    MP4_files = glob.glob('*.MK4')
    mp4_files = glob.glob('*.mp4')
    webm_files = glob.glob('*.webm')
    ts_files = glob.glob('*.ts')

    if len(avi_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting avi videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(avi_files)

    if len(MKV_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting MKV videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(MKV_files)

    if len(AVI_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting AVI videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(AVI_files)

    if len(MP4_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting MP4 videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(MP4_files)

    if len(mp4_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting mp4 videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(mp4_files)

    if len(webm_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting webm videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(webm_files)

    if len(ts_files) > 0:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] Converting ts videos to mkv format')
        change_extension(ts_files)
        
def encode_480(filename):
    FILENAME_PATH = filename
    newname = filename.split('.')[0]
    newname_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, newname)

    poster_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -ss  00:00:10 -i {FILENAME_PATH} -vframes  1 -q:v  2 poster.jpg'
    os.system(poster_cmd)
    
    if not os.path.exists(newname_path):
        os.mkdir(newname_path)

    os.replace('poster.jpg', os.path.join(newname_path, 'poster.jpg'))
    

    ffmpeg480_cmd = f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {FILENAME_PATH} -sn -c:a aac -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -maxrate 1024k -bufsize 1536k -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_segment_filename 4835JRK9%03d.ts 480p.m3u8'
    os.system(ffmpeg480_cmd)
    
    # os.remove(FILENAME_PATH)
    
    ts_files = glob.glob('*.ts')
    for ts_file in ts_files:
        os.replace(ts_file, os.path.join(newname_path, ts_file))
    
    master_text = '''#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1500000,RESOLUTION=854x480
480p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=840000,RESOLUTION=640x360
360p.m3u8
'''
    with open('master.m3u8', 'w') as f:
        f.write(master_text)
    
    m3u8_files = glob.glob('*.m3u8')
    for m3u8_file in m3u8_files:
        os.replace(m3u8_file, os.path.join(newname_path, m3u8_file))


def encode_360(filename):
    FILENAME_PATH = filename
    newname = filename.split('.')[0]
    newname_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH,newname)
    poster_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10 -i {FILENAME_PATH} -vframes 1 -q:v 2 poster.jpg'
    os.system(poster_cmd)
    if not os.path.exists(newname_path):
        os.mkdir(newname_path)
    os.replace('poster.jpg',os.path.join(newname_path, 'poster.jpg'))

    
    ffmpeg360_cmd = f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {FILENAME_PATH} -sn -c:a aac -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -maxrate 512k -bufsize 768k -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_segment_filename 365RL6TJ%03d.ts 360p.m3u8'
    os.system(ffmpeg360_cmd)
    # return
    
    
    ts_files = glob.glob('*.ts')
    for ts_file in ts_files:
        os.replace(ts_file, os.path.join(newname_path,ts_file))
    master_text = '''#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=840000,RESOLUTION=640x360
360p.m3u8
    '''
    with open('master.m3u8', 'w') as f:
        f.write(master_text)
    m3u8_files = glob.glob('*.m3u8')
    for m3u8_file in m3u8_files:
        os.replace(m3u8_file, os.path.join(newname_path, m3u8_file))


def encode_720(filename):
    FILENAME_PATH = filename
    newname = filename.split('.')[0]
    newname_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH,newname)
    poster_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10 -i {FILENAME_PATH} -vframes 1 -q:v 2 poster.jpg'
    os.system(poster_cmd)

    if not os.path.exists(newname_path):
        os.mkdir(newname_path)

    os.replace('poster.jpg',os.path.join(newname_path, 'poster.jpg'))

    ffmpeg720_cmd = f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {FILENAME_PATH} -sn -c:a aac -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -maxrate 2048k -bufsize 3072k -b:a 160k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_segment_filename 7269TKL0%03d.ts 720p.m3u8'
    os.system(ffmpeg720_cmd)

    # os.remove(FILENAME_PATH)

    ts_files = glob.glob('*.ts')
    for ts_file in ts_files:
        os.replace(ts_file, os.path.join(newname_path,ts_file))
        
    m3u8_text = '''#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
720p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=840000,RESOLUTION=640x360
360p.m3u8        
        '''

    with open('master.m3u8','w') as f:
        f.write(m3u8_text)
            
    m3u8_files = glob.glob('*.m3u8')
    for m3u8_file in m3u8_files:
        os.replace(m3u8_file, os.path.join(newname_path,m3u8_file))  


def encode_1080(filename):
    FILENAME_PATH = filename
    newname = filename.split('.')[0]
    newname_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, newname)
    poster_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10 -i {FILENAME_PATH} -vframes 1 -q:v 2 poster.jpg'
    os.system(poster_cmd)

    if not os.path.exists(newname_path):
        os.mkdir(newname_path)

    os.replace('poster.jpg', os.path.join(newname_path, 'poster.jpg'))

    ffmpeg1080_cmd = f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {FILENAME_PATH} -sn -c:a aac -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 6000k -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_segment_filename 108YUT8T%03d.ts 1080p.m3u8'
    os.system(ffmpeg1080_cmd)

    # os.remove(FILENAME_PATH)

    ts_files = glob.glob('*.ts')
    for ts_file in ts_files:
        os.replace(ts_file, os.path.join(newname_path, ts_file))

    m3u8_text = '''#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4000000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080
1080p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
720p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=840000,RESOLUTION=640x360
360p.m3u8
'''

    with open('master.m3u8', 'w') as f:
        f.write(m3u8_text)

    m3u8_files = glob.glob('*.m3u8')
    for m3u8_file in m3u8_files:
        os.replace(m3u8_file, os.path.join(newname_path, m3u8_file))



def vod(filename, resolution):
    os.replace(filename,filename.replace(' ','_'))
    filename = filename.replace(' ','_')
    FILENAME_PATH = filename
    width_cmd = f'ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of default=nw=1:nk=1 {FILENAME_PATH}'
    height_cmd= f'ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 {FILENAME_PATH}'

    width_result = subprocess.run(width_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    width = width_result.stdout.strip().decode('utf-8')

    height_result = subprocess.run(height_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    height = height_result.stdout.strip().decode('utf-8')

    if not os.path.exists(VIDEO_PATH):
        os.mkdir(VIDEO_PATH)

    if resolution == 360: 
        write_log(f'Encoding {filename} in 360p') 
        encode_360(filename)

    if resolution == 720 :
        if int(height) >=400 :
            if int(height) <= 700:
                query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding480' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                executedb(query)
                write_log(f'Encoding {filename} in 480p')
                encode_480(filename) 
                query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done480' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                executedb(query)
                query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 2 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                executedb(query)
            else:
                if int(height) >= 800:
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding720' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    write_log(f'Encoding {filename} in 720p')
                    encode_720(filename)   
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done720' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 3 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding1080' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    write_log(f'Encoding {filename} in 720p')
                    encode_1080(filename)   
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done1080' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 4 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                else:
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding720' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    write_log(f'Encoding {filename} in 720p')
                    encode_720(filename)   
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done720' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                    query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 3 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{filename.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                    executedb(query)
                
        
            
        os.remove(filename)


def move_to_rclone():
    if not os.path.exists(RCLONE_PATH):
        os.mkdir(RCLONE_PATH)
    folders = os.listdir(VIDEO_PATH)
    if len(folders) > 0:
        for folder in folders:
            folder_in_rclone = os.path.join(RCLONE_PATH, folder)
            if not os.path.exists(folder_in_rclone):
                os.mkdir(folder_in_rclone)
            files = os.listdir(os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, folder))
            for file in files:
                os.replace(os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, folder, file), os.path.join(folder_in_rclone, file))
            os.system(MOVE_CMD.format(folder_in_rclone))
        if len(os.listdir(os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, folder))) == 0:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(VIDEO_PATH, folder))
    # rclone_folders = os.listdir(RCLONE_PATH)
    # if len(rclone_folders)> 0:
    #     for rclone_folder in rclone_folders:
    #         os.system(MOVE_CMD.format(rclone_folder))

def get_length(input_video):
    result = subprocess.run(['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', input_video], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    try:
        output = float(result.stdout)
    except:
        output = 0
    return output

def move_to_error(file):
    if not os.path.exists(ERROR_PATH):
        os.mkdir(ERROR_PATH)
    print(f'[red][-][/red] Moving {file} to the error folder')
    os.replace(file, os.path.join(ERROR_PATH, file.split('/')[-1]))

def main():
    db = sql.connect(
        host=MYSQL_HOST,
        user=MYSQL_USER,
        password=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=MYSQL_DB
    )

    def get_video_data(file_uid):
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = f"""SELECT id, post_title, file_uid, group_id FROM videos WHERE file_uid LIKE %s"""
        cursor.execute(query, (f'%{file_uid}%',))
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        return data if data else None
    
    if os.path.exists(UPLOAD_PATH):
        upload_files = os.listdir(UPLOAD_PATH)
        upload_files = [os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, x) for x in upload_files]
        upload_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    else:
        upload_files = []

    if len(upload_files) > 0:
        for upload_file in upload_files:
            if get_length(upload_file) < VIDEO_LENGTH:
                move_to_error(upload_file)
                write_log(f'Length of {upload_file} is less than 60 sec.  Moving to error folder')
                continue
            try:
                os.replace(upload_file, upload_file.split('/')[-1])
                query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'uploaded' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{upload_file.replace(".mkv","").replace(".mp4","")}'"""
                executedb(query)
            except:
                print(e)
                continue
            change_all_videos_extension()

            mkv_files = glob.glob('*.mkv')
            if len(mkv_files) > 0:
                for mkv_file in mkv_files:
                    try:
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding360' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        vod(mkv_file, 360)
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done360' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 1 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)

                        
                        vod(mkv_file, 720)
                        
                    except Exception as e:
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'error' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        video_data = get_video_data(
                            mkv_file.replace(".mkv", ""))
                        if video_data:
                            cursor = db.cursor()
                            video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id = video_data
                            error_log_query = f"""INSERT INTO error_logs (video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id, log, created_at, updated_at) 
                                                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())"""
                            cursor.execute(
                                error_log_query, (video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id, str(e)))
                            db.commit()
                        write_log(f'Error: {e}')
                        move_to_error(mkv_file)
                    move_to_rclone()
    else:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] No new video found on upload folder')

    if os.path.exists(UPLOAD_PATH2):
        upload_files2 = os.listdir(UPLOAD_PATH2)
        upload_files2 = [os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH2, x) for x in upload_files2]
        upload_files2.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    else:
        upload_files2 = []

    if len(upload_files2) > 0:
        for upload_file2 in upload_files2:
            if get_length(upload_file2) < VIDEO_LENGTH:
                move_to_error(upload_file2)
                continue
            if len(os.listdir(UPLOAD_PATH)) != 0:
                main()
            try:
                os.replace(upload_file2, upload_file2.split('/')[-1])
                query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'uploaded' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{upload_file2.replace(".mkv","").replace(".mp4","")}'"""
                executedb(query)
            except:
                continue

            change_all_videos_extension()

            mkv_files = glob.glob('*.mkv')
            if len(mkv_files) > 0:
                for mkv_file in mkv_files:
                    try:
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'encoding360' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        vod(mkv_file, 360)
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'done360' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET quality = 1 WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)


                        vod(mkv_file, 720)

                    except Exception as e:
                        query = f"""UPDATE videos SET encoding_status = 'error' WHERE file_uid LIKE '%{mkv_file.replace(".mkv","")}'"""
                        executedb(query)
                        video_data = get_video_data(
                            mkv_file.replace(".mkv", ""))
                        if video_data:
                            cursor = db.cursor()
                            video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id = video_data
                            error_log_query = f"""INSERT INTO error_logs (video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id, log, created_at, updated_at) 
                                                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())"""
                            cursor.execute(
                                error_log_query, (video_id, video_title, video_uid, group_id, str(e)))
                            db.commit()
                        write_log(f'Error: {e}')
                        move_to_error(mkv_file)
            move_to_rclone()
    else:
        print(f'[{time_now()}] No new video found on upload2 folder.')
    move_to_rclone()
    db.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
        for i in range(WAIT):
            print(f'[green][+][/green] Waiting for {WAIT-i} seconds  ', end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
```

looking for suggestion to improve encoding speed

Comment: This is not about your Python code. This is about *running* ffmpeg and your machine.

Comment: how to speedup ffmpeg cmd?

Comment: @MarcCuadras **(1)** Check if FFmpeg can work with your GPU. See [Intro to FFmpeg Hardware Acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro). Try any tutorial about using hardware acceleration in command line FFmpeg then use those tested & working commands in your app. **(2)** It might not be possible to get any more faster speed out of FFmpeg. It is just a free encoder (or open-source experiment), and not trying to the best for performance. If you're doing professional videos and your business needs speed then just buy a real H264 encoder tool (_eg:_ Elecard, Panasonic, Sony, etc)